# how to join three tables with one output

Tags: mysql, sql, json

i have the sql statement below of which i wanted 3 tables to be joined and have 1 output. The thing is, there is no error but it did not show my desired output.

```
$sql = "select distinct(sales_table.sales_id), trades_table.t_symbol, round(sum(trades_table.t_volume),2) as totalvol from trades_table inner join accounts_table on trades_table.t_login = accounts_table.a_login inner join sales_table where accounts_table.a_comment = sales_table.sales_id  group by trades_table.t_symbol";
```

My Table Files

sales_table

| sales_id | sales_name |
| --- | --- |
| john | john doe |
| jake | jake dog |

trades_table

| t_deal | t_login | t_symbol | t_volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 4000 | fb | 2.00 |
| 1112 | 4001 | tesla | 1.00 |
| 1113 | 4001 | tesla | 1.00 |
| 1114 | 4002 | apple | 3.00 |

accounts_table

| a_login | a_name | a_comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4000 | test1 | john |
| 4001 | test2 | john |
| 4002 | test2 | jake |

The desired output which i have in mind is

john

| trades_table.t_symbol | round(sum(trades_table.t_volume),2) |
| --- | --- |
| fb | 2.00 |
| tesla | 2.00 |

jake

| trades_table.t_symbol | round(sum(trades_table.t_volume),2) |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 3.00 |

I hope someone can help me on how to properly use inner join for 3 tables.

Thank you very much

Comment: i don't know what happened but when i am creating this post, table format works properly fine and it shows on the preview, but when i post, the thing you seen above happens

Comment: Do you mean join three _databases_ or three _tables_? Please also output what you're currently getting.

Comment: 3 tables to have 1 output.

output from the sql code above is
sales_id: john
t_symbol: fb
totalvol: 2.00

sales_id: john
t_symbol: tesla
totalvol: 2.00

sales_id: jake
t_symbol: apple
totalvol: 3.00

Comment: Please share more details. How do you run that query? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need in simple

```
SELECT t1.a_login, t3.t_symbol, SUM(t3.t_volume) total_volume
FROM accounts_table t1
JOIN sales_table t2 ON t1.a_comment = t2.sales_id
JOIN trades_table t3 ON t1.a_login = t3.t_login
GROUP BY t1.a_login, t3.t_symbol
```

If you need in the data for specified `t1.a_login` only then add according WHERE.